# Copying a template type 2D array to a class member

Tags: c++, templates, multidimensional-array

I have a class which holds a 2D array as a member.

```
int neighbourhood[30][5];
```

And a class member function that needs to copy a incoming array;

```
template <typename TwoDArray>
void set_neighbourhood(TwoDArray& nbh)
{
    neighbourhood = nbh;
}
```

As evident from the code, a template type is in place. Why use templates? Well passing 2D arrays seems to easy and clean according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

But I am getting a L-value error and seems that this is not the right syntax to copy the array.

Definitely I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have it yet you may need to write a method for the = operator. Below is an example of one I wrote recently.

for example in your constructor you'll need to write

```
SingleLink& operator=(SingleLink);
```

then outside constructor

```
template<typename K, typename V>
SingleLink<K,V>& SingleLink<K,V>::operator=(SingleLink sl){
    swap(head_, sl.head_);
    swap(tail_, sl.tail_);
    return *this;
}
```

In my case head_ and tail_ are some of my class members. Also I took in two template types while it seems you only have to worry about one.

Comment: Yep, I had to write a method for it. That was the problem.